# svg - Aligning text outside circular arc d3js

Tags: d3.js, svg

Can someone help me to create below image using d3js. I able to create pie chart as required but stuck to render outer text with arrows and all.

[Wheel with outer text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JE0v.png)

As of know I have achieved circle creation using below code.

```
 var svg = d3.select("svg");
var margin = {top: 40, right: 45, bottom: 30, left: 40};
console.log(svg);
var width = svg.attr('width');

var height = svg.attr('height');


var radius = Math.min(width, height)/2;
var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
var hoverStyle = {
    zindex: '2px'
};

var hoverExitStyle = {
    zindex: "0px"
}

var animateSpeed = 500;

// Define a Pie
var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {return d.number});

// define pie section
var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

//
var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

// Get pie sections based on the data.
var pieSections = pie(data);

var arc = g.selectAll('.arc')
    .data(pieSections)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .append('a')
    .attr("href", function(d) { return d.data.url; });

arc.append("path")
    .attr("d", path).transition()
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.data.color; });

arc.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.title; });
```

Comment: There are surely many people able and willing to help you out with this—if you pay them accordingly. If you want free help from the Stack Overflow community, please take some time and learn [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]. This site's rules require that you show your efforts and provide at least the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I will take care all the rules in future and please accept my apologies if i did something wrong here. This is the first question I asked in stackoverflow.

Comment: The OP is probably unaware of how much work both of these things are (the curved text and arrowheads); they probably don't even know the google terms that they should be looking for.

@Shubham, you won't catch as much flak if you phrase it differently... i.e. "how would I go about creating curved labels like this?" The way you phrased it, it comes off as "do both of these two hard things for me." Always ask questions with the intent to learn, not for someone to just give you a solution—the former helps everyone, and the latter does everyone a disservice, INCLUDING YOU.

Comment: @Shubham You might find the following article helpful: [*Placing Texts on Arcs with D3.js*](https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs.html).

Answer (score 0):

The text and the arrows are two separate concerns that probably merit their own questions.

**Curved text**
To do text on a path with d3, you might want to look at the [textpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) documentation. It's going to be a little tricky; basically, you'll want to create *a second* `d3.arc()` generator with a slightly longer outer radius. Use the longer one to set the `d` attribute of `path` elements (that you need to create) inside the SVG's `defs` object, and reference those `path` elements' `id`s from `textpath` elements (that you also need to create).

**Curved arrows**
To accomplish this exactly like the image, you're probably going to need to some manual construction (including figuring out the math!) of the `d` attribute yourself to add appropriate arrowheads (see the SVG path [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)). If you're doing a static image, it might be faster to just create the lines (again, using a longer-radius `d3.arc()` generator), and export the SVG with something like [SVG crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) to a drawing program like Illustrator or Inkscape, and add the arrowheads there.